# Original or not?

Tags: logarithms

https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7bcX.jpg
http://i113.photobucket.com/albums/n206/dharanis1/lo3_zps0a03f5d0.jpg

I am wondering if anyone on this forum can throw some light on the authenticity of the mathematical terms used in the linked images. The originator claims it's a new concept he has developed for working with logs.my question is...is this indeed a new mathematical approach or a piece of hokum?

Comment: So the claim is that for every $v$ (real?), the sequence $$a_n = 2^n \left( v^{1/2^n} - v^{-1/2^n}\right)$ converges towards $ln(v)$?
First comment: It might be fast to compute it like that, but numerically very unstable (you take giant roots, substract these numbers that are almost equal to get a really small number and then multiply it by a really big number ($2^n$). This might be fast, but numerically really, really unstable.

Answer (score 1):

It is the case that
$$\lim_{N\to\infty}N(v^{1/(2N)}-v^{-1/(2N)})=\ln v$$
for $v>0$. The stated result is a special case of this.
To prove this I would write $\ln v= a$ and $x=1/2N$.
The limit becomes
$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{e^{ax}-e^{-ax}}{2x}$$
and you can apply, say L'Hospital's rule.

So, pretty routine stuff.